# What extra logic does this need to exceed a depth of three in this Sierpinski triangle?

Tags: python

Right now I'm trying to use this very simple loop to draw a **Sierpinski triangle** in Python, but with the current loop I cannot exceed a depth of 3.

```
import turtle as t

def sier(n, length):

    if (n == 0):

        return

    for i in range(3):

        sier(n - 1, length / 2)

        t.fd(length)

        t.lt(120)

sier(3, 100)

t.exitonclick()
```

What logic do I need to add to the loop for it to be able to be infinitely recursive?

Comment: What have you done to try to exceed a depth of 3?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x, by any chance?  `/` does integer division if both arguments are integers in those versions.  So your first three levels have lengths of 100, 50, and 25 - but the fourth level would use 12 instead of the correct 12.5, so things stop lining up properly.  If that's the problem, choosing a starting length that's a power of two (64 or 128, perhaps) would let you go more levels before having to deal with fractional lengths.

Comment: @ScottHunter if you have a console, run it with any number above three. What I believe is happening is that it tries to draw the triangle with that number of sides.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm running 3.6 on Pycharm. What I believe the issue is is that that 3 in the loop is telling the turtle to both draw three triangles but also to draw the three sides of the triangle. If you'd like to see how I mean this, copy my code into a Python console and put a number like two into the loop instead of three.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of recursive function is seldon that the deepmost call "do nothing". Instead, the deep-most call is the one performing the one basic step, reduced to the bare minimum and simple act - and then return. The combination of this bare minimum act with the complexity added on the calls further up on the stack is what "do the magic".

So, usually, in trivial text-book examples of recursive function, the "bare minimal" is to return a "1", which is then added-to or multiplied-by other results in the structure.

In the case of line-art fractals like Sierpinsk or Koch curves, the bare minimal is to actually *draw* the minimal desired image element. In your code, you are calling t.fd in the upper-calls on the stack, and drawing nothing on the deep-most call - that is where your code is wrong.

Thus, talking code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, tracer

def triangle(n, length):
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        t.fd(length)
        t.left(120)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()

def sierpinski(n, length):
    if n == 0 or length <= 1:
        triangle(n, length)
    else:
        # draw bottom-left triangle
        sierpinski(n - 1, length / 2)
        # position turtle at corner of bottom.left triangle:
        t.fd(length / 2)
        sierpinski(n - 1, length / 2)
        # Position turtle at the bottom-left corner
        # of the top the 3 triangle-set comprising this level:
        t.left(120)
        t.fd(length / 2)
        t.left(240)
        #draw top-most triangle
        sierpinski(n - 1, length / 2)
        # reposition turtle at lower-left corner:
        t.left(240)
        t.fd(length / 2)
        t.left(120)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Turtle()
    # shut down all animation:
    tracer(100,0)
    t.hideturtle()
    t.penup()
    sierpinski(4, 400)
    t.screen.exitonclick()
```

As turtle is intended to be a didactic module, it is by default slow, even setting the speed to "0", not to show animations. To really speed thing up, add these lines to the begging of the code:

```
from turtle import tracer
tracer(100,0)
```

to effectively disable all animation - otherwise, depth level 4 is slow, and 5 is unfeasible.

Comment: thank you for the code with explanation of what everything does! This far I've been going off of other stuff not really knowing what the code does, so this is great.

Comment: It seems to be throwing quite a few errors either about self being required and then not recognizing it or about the argument length not being a distance in def triangle. It also says that it cannot find module tracer.

Comment: I just copied the code from above, as it is, pasted in a new script and run it with Python 3.6,  2.7 and pypy3 - with none of the errors you mention. A, I see, you probably tried to mix this with your code - note that I had used `t` as a Turtle instance, not as the turtle module as you do in your example code.

Comment: And as an anedocte, much to my surprise, it is actually quite slower in pypy

Comment: Looks like its working now, I must have changed something and forgotten. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop as part of your recursive call. The call to **sier** is what makes the function loop. And you have your recursive termination case with the n==0 check to end the loop.

Example

```
>>> def sier(n, length):
...     if(n==0):
...         return
...     print("n:" + str(n) + ", length: " + str(length))
...     sier(n-1, length/2)
... 
>>> sier(10,100)
n:10, length: 100
n:9, length: 50.0
n:8, length: 25.0
n:7, length: 12.5
n:6, length: 6.25
n:5, length: 3.125
n:4, length: 1.5625
n:3, length: 0.78125
n:2, length: 0.390625
n:1, length: 0.1953125
>>> sier(3,100)
n:3, length: 100
n:2, length: 50.0
n:1, length: 25.0
```

Comment: How would I translate this code into Turtle graphics?